# Restarted my laptop while installing the new 14.04 and now can't make it to start up

Tags: boot

While I was installing the new Ubuntu version, my laptop was re-started and now I'm not able to make it to load or start up. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it again following the same method. This should sort everything out and give your installation a fair chance.